# How to add class directive after element is compiled and linked

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive:

```
.directive('test', function(){
     return {
          restrict: 'C'
          ....
     }
 })
```

I would like to have this directive conditionally added to an element:

```
<div ng-class="{test: testActive}">
```

This doesn't work ([here is a Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DjzNmAzByVrhTB9lcd9P?p=preview) with the variations I've tried so far).

I'm guessing it would work if I $compiled() the element again, but I'm guessing calling $compile on an already $compiled() element comes with it's own set of problems (or is this something angular supports?).

Looking for suggestions/alternatives.

Comment: It is being conditionally added - but you are trying to toggle it, right?

Comment: No - the only case it gets linked in the plnkr is when you use class="testActive ? 'test' : ''".   It gets linked in this case regardless of the value of testActive.  I think angular just does a regex on the class attribute internally.  The directive never gets linked when using ng-class.

Comment: I should note the class gets added, but the corresponding directive is not created (as it would be if the class existed at the time the element was $compiled().

Comment: That's exactly right - ng-class just adds a class name, it does not compile a directive. The only built-in way to conditionally toggle/apply is to use `ng-if` or `ng-switch` on the element.